# What are the benefits of using gridgain instead of ignite?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I want to move my database from Oracle to Gridgain . I wanted to know the benefits of Gridgain over ignite? what does Gridgain add that is more than ignite offers.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a opinion based question and answer site

Answer (score 0):

You can find comparison of different GridGain editions on the following page: https://www.gridgain.com/products/software

GridGain Professional Edition has all the same features, that Ignite does. You can learn about additional features, included into Enterprise and Ultimate editions, on the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all information on the [GridGain](https://www.gridgain.com/) website, so all you need to do is spend a bit of time reading.

Apache Ignite is the open source technology underpinning GridGain's paid products. You can find a list of its features [here](https://www.gridgain.com/technology/apache-ignite).

Paid products are described on the [GridGain products](https://www.gridgain.com/products/gridgain-products) page, for example see this paragraph:

> The [**GridGain Professional Edition**](https://www.gridgain.com/products/software/professional-edition) is a supported version of Apache Ignite with additional bug fixes not yet released in the open source project. The [**GridGain Enterprise Edition**](https://www.gridgain.com/products/software/enterprise-edition) enhances Apache Ignite with additional features and testing which make it easier to deploy, manage and secure in production environments. The [**GridGain Ultimate Edition**](https://www.gridgain.com/products/software/ultimate-edition) provides cluster snapshot backup features which are crucial when running the Persistent Store feature in production environments. All of the GridGain editions can be downloaded for a free 30 day trial.

There are more details behind the respective links.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to replace Oracle with Ignite then, most likely, [Ignite persistence](https://ignite.apache.org/arch/persistence.html) will be used (so that the durability property is preserved).

GridGain Ultimate Edition goes with [snapshots/backups & recovery](https://docs.gridgain.com/docs/overview-snapshots) capabilities essential for every disk-based databases. The capabilities are designed and work with Ignite persistence.